# ionic 3 side menu not working in ios

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, side-menu

My ionic side menu is working in android mobile but in ios i am not getting.

here is the code for .html

```
<button ion-button menuToggle icon-only class="menuButton"> 
  <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
</button>

<ion-menu [content]="mycontent">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <p>some menu content, could be list items</p>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav #mycontent ></ion-nav>
```

i dont understand where is my issue is if you need anything please let me know

> my side menu is working in android and browser except ios

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try adding type="overlay" to the sidemenu:

```
<ion-menu [content]="mycontent" type="overlay">
```

Answer (score 2):

use click function instead of menuToggle

```
<button ion-button icon-only start (click)="openSideMenu()">
     <ion-icon name="md-menu"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

open menu using

```
openSideMenu() {
   this.menuCtrl.enable(true)
    this.menuCtrl.toggle();    
}
```

disable menu before you push to new page

```
this.menuCtrl.enable(false)
```